# Trying to create a view in SQL Server 2014 to read the table data in a different format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014. Table 'X' has a column 'Desc2' in which data is in the format

```
'VT000379_001: Low Low Alarm Limit 5'  
'VT000379_001_001: Low Low Alarm Limit 5' .
```

I am trying to create a view to remove the '_001', so the result should be:

```
'VT000379: Low Low Alarm Limit 5'   
'VT000379_001: Low Low Alarm Limit 5'
```

The logic I have been trying is

```
Instr =: = 12

x= left(12) = VT000379_001

if x has 1 underscore

inst = "_" position 1 =VT000379

if x has 2 underscores

inst ="_" position 2 =VT000379_001
```

Can someone help me out withthis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove just the 1st occurrence of `'_001'`:

```
create table tablename(col varchar(max));
insert into tablename(col) values
  ('VT000379_001: Low Low Alarm Limit 5'),
  ('VT000379_001_001: Low Low Alarm Limit 5'),
  ('VT000379: Low Low Alarm Limit 5');

select 
  case 
    when charindex('_001', col) = 0 then col
    else left(col, charindex('_001', col) - 1) + right(col, len(col) - charindex('_001', col) - 3)
  end result
from tablename
```

or with `stuff()`:

```
select 
  case 
    when charindex('_001', col) = 0 then col
    else stuff(col, charindex('_001', col), len('_001'), '') 
  end result
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=707bf04a32ad1fade265418e5a240a96).
Results:

```
result
------
VT000379: Low Low Alarm Limit 5
VT000379_001: Low Low Alarm Limit 5
VT000379: Low Low Alarm Limit 5
```

Comment: Thank you:) instead of creating a table , i have created a view with Left function that you have provided. Thank you very much once again.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example data, how about using `replace()`?

```
replace(desc2, '_001:', ':')
```